# Change the background colour and the query-background colour in SearchView fails

Tags: android, searchview

I'm trying to change the colour of my SearchView, how ever when I try following xml code

```
<SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view_id"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:queryHint="Search"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:queryBackground="#FFF"/>
```

I get an error that states:

> Error:error: '#FFF' is incompatible with attribute
>   android:queryBackground (attr) reference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `android:queryBackground` only accept a resource ID. Just use a color resource instead of hardcoded hex. Keep this in mind.

> Attribute queryBackground is only used in API level 21

```
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

 <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view_id"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:queryHint="Search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:queryBackground="@color/white"/>
```